# Change in node_modules folder structure?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm having trouble even explaining this one.

I want the desired behaviour as below for npm install (each package has a sub-folder)

[image]

But for some projects it seems to install all the dependencies like this.

[image]

Comment: What's the relevance of the structure of folder? The node or express manage this

Comment: I'm curious as to what makes the command `npm install` fetch and save the dependencies in folders as per the name of the package, as opposed to them all being in the one (node_modules) folder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

npm 3+ has a new feature where it tries to install modules and dependancies in as flat a structure as possible.

More information in [v3.0.0 changelog](https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v3.0.0).

Comment: So is this what is [described here](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders#node-modules)?

Do you have any other information about this feature?

Comment: Thanks for this. I had wondered if it was any error on my part.