# `npm install` is installing dozens of dependencies

Tags: npm, npm-install

My package.json only has express, mongodb, and pug listed as dependencies. When I delete my node_modules folder and run `npm install` in the root of my app, it installs 51 dependencies (shown below). not sure what is going on...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

npm v3 dependency resolution works that way and might install ["some secondary dependencies (dependencies of dependencies) in a flat way"](https://docs.npmjs.com/how-npm-works/npm3).

You can also refer to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33649913/change-in-node-modules-folder-structure).